# How to alphabetize x labels and change colors in pandas bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

So I have this code that is creating a bar chart, but as it is now, the x-label is in descending order.

```
unq1 = df1['Category'].value_counts()
unq1.plot(kind='bar', rot=270, colormap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

I want the x-label order to be alphabetical, from A-Z, Left-Right. Also when using the colormap attribute, all the bars are the same color. I want them to change throughout, particular colormap doesn't matter. I have tried to find help online to no avail.
Thank you!

data frame looks like this:

```
                                                     App  ...         Android Ver
0         Photo Editor & Candy Camera & Grid & ScrapBook  ...        4.0.3 and up
1                                    Coloring book moana  ...        4.0.3 and up
```

'Price' column is a float. Not shown because there are too many columns.

Comment: please share your data.  You can add the output of something like `df1.head(20).to_dict()` or the like

Comment: I added what I could copy, too many columns. Price is a float though if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

How about renaming the ticks of the plot?

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create alphabet
abc = [chr(i) for i in range(0+ord('a'),len(unq1)+ord('a'))]


# open figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
unq1.plot(kind='bar', rot=270, colormap='viridis')
# get ticks
idx = ax.get_xticks()
# set ticks/rename
ax.set_xticklabels( np.array(abc)[idx] )
```

Note that one can only index numpy-arrays not lists => cast it to a numpy-array first ;)